# Both buttons animate when i click one button in the HeroCard on Slack

Tags: button, botframework, bots, slack

I have a slack bot based on Bot builder SDK v4.0.
When i add HeroCard with two buttons, slack renders the card correctly, when i click one button, both button animates, but it returns correct button click.

```
var reply = sc.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
var card = new HeroCard
{
    Text = "Do you want to continue",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
    {
        new CardAction() { Title = "Yes", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "Yes"},
        new CardAction() { Title = "No", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "No"},
    },
};
reply.Attachments = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Attachment> { 
    card.ToAttachment() 
};
var options = new PromptOptions()
{
    Prompt = reply,
};
return await sc.PromptAsync(DialogIds.MyPrompt, options);
```

I get the correct reply, however, one button should animate

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. The following solution works by assigning each button as an individual activity. The activities are then sent using the `sendActivities()` method. The drawback is it places both buttons vertically rather than horizontally. The orientation doesn't appear to be alterable as the `sendActivities()` method doesn't take any options for defining the display type (i.e. `ListStyle.list`, `ListStyle.inline`, etc.).

That being said, it does work.

```js
const reply1 = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
const reply2 = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };

const yesBtn = { type: ActionTypes.PostBack, title: 'Yes', value: 'Yes' };
const noBtn = { type: ActionTypes.PostBack, title: 'No', value: 'No' };

const card1 = CardFactory.heroCard(
  'Do you want to continue',
  undefined,
  [yesBtn]
);
const card2 = CardFactory.heroCard(
  undefined,
  undefined,
  [noBtn]
);

reply1.attachments = [card1];
reply2.attachments = [card2];

await stepContext.context.sendActivities([reply1, reply2])
```

[image]

Hope of help!

Answer (score 0):

I think @StevenKanberg trick would do. 
However, same workaround can not apply for Adaptive Card scenario.
I see the same issue with Adaptive card where it has more than one action buttons.